# For loop: Store items in list, then count and print numbers of items in that list

Tags: python, bots, discord, reddit, praw

Trying to count items from Reddit API, and adding them all to a list, and then printing amount of lines in said list.

So, I have tried a few things, but they have all turned out unsuccessful so far. Why is it that this doesn't count correctly, and prints amounts of items in "redditqueue"? Any help/suggestions are mostly welcome!

```
x = []
for item in redditqueue: #redditqueue is a placeholder
    x.append(item)
    Count = x.count()
    print(Count)
```

What I want is for the code to print 2 if there's 2 items in redditqueue, but it's simply printing the following:

```
0
0
```

Answer (score 1):

`len()` is what you want. Try this:

```
x = []
for item in redditqueue:
    x.append(item)
    print(len(x))
```

Comment: Ah, thanks a ton, I thought about len but ruled against it . It's been a while since I worked with python, and I had the misconception that len() simply counted amount of characters - but that's not the case for lists by the looks of it.

Comment: Right, `len()` will count characters with a string, and items for a list.

Comment: `len` returns the number of items in any iterable. For strings it is the number of characters. For lists it is the number of elements. For dicts it is the number of keys. Etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how many items are in `redditqueue`, then simply get the list length:

```
print(len(redditqueue))
```

If `redditqueue` is some sort of iterator or generator, then make a list of its entire sequence and take the length of that.

```
print len(list(redditqueue))
```

If that's too long, and you need to count the quantity of items in the list, then don't accumulate the elements in yet another structure ... just *count*:

```
for count, item in enumerate(redditqueue):
    pass

print(count)
```